# Rails has_many :through with the where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've built easy Twitter application in Rails.

Now I would like `to choose three random users that are not followed by the current user`.

Here is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tweets, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :followerships, class_name: 'Followership', foreign_key: 'followed_id'
    has_many :followedships, class_name: 'Followership', foreign_key: 'follower_id'
    has_many :followers, through: :followerships, source: :follower
    has_many :followed, through: :followedships, source: :followed
end

class Followership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
    validates :follower_id, presence: true
    validates :followed_id, presence: true
end

class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I tried to use the following query:

```
User.where.not(followers: current_user).order("RANDOM()").limit(3)
```

But it obviously doesn't work as I get `no such column: users.follower_id` error.

Is it even possible to do without sql query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
already_following = current_user.followed.map(&:id)
@users = User.where.not(id: already_following).order("RANDOM()").limit(3)
```

Basically what I did, was got the list of users already being followed. Then you check the User table for id's not matching users already being followed.